# T-SQL Update Record need to add condition which requires JOIN

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

I have an existing query which updates specific values (represented as Col1, Col2, Col3 here) of all records in a table to the current values of those Cols for a defined source record in that table. This source record is defined by an Id which is a Foreign Key in this table (represented as FKRecId here)

```
DECLARE @SourceRecordId VARCHAR(50)
SET @SourceRecordId= N'{the Id}'

UPDATE dbo.TargetTable
   SET [Col1] = SourceData.Col1
      ,[Col2] = SourceData.Col2
      ,[Col3] = SourceData.Col3
     FROM ( SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM TargetTable WHERE FKRecId = @SourceRecordId ) SourceData
WHERE ((FKRecId != @SourceRecordId) AND 
(CAST(TargetTable.Col1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) != CAST(SourceData.Col1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) OR 
CAST(TargetTable.Col2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) != CAST(SourceData.Col2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) OR 
CAST(TargetTable.Col3 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) != CAST(SourceData.Col3 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) )

GO
```

This currently updates all other records in the table using the values defined in the source record. However, I now need to add a further condition that it only updates those records where they are the same "type" as the source record. The value of "Type" is held in another table - (the Primary Key of that table entry is the Foreign Key Id mentioned above).

I have attempted to modify the query to incorporate a JOIN but I have limited T-SQL experience and have been struggling to get the syntax correct. The portion I have tried to update is shown below

```
     FROM ( SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM TargetTable WHERE FKRecId = @SourceRecordId ) SourceData
JOIN dbo.OtherTable t On t.PrimaryKey = TargetTable.FKRecId
WHERE ((FKRecId != @SourceRecordId) AND (t.Type = KnownType) AND
```

This leads to an error in the SQL Server query editor at the TargetTable element of the JOIN statement. If I just put in the column name the intellisense error shows as `"Invalid column name"`, if i qualify it with the table name it becomes `"the multi part identifier xxx could not be bound"`.

Any help on where I'm going wrong with my syntax would be appreciated, I'd also appreciate if anyone could point me towards an online reference resource with examples of T-SQL statements that goes beyond the basics that I may haev fiound the answer to this in.

Thanks.

Comment: `TargetTable` already has alias `SourceData` to that moment.

Comment: And you are not returning FKRecId column from `SourceData` subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an UPDATE statement like this:

```
DECLARE @SourceRecordId VARCHAR(50)
SET @SourceRecordId= N'{the Id}'

UPDATE U
SET U.[Col1] = SourceData.Col1
   ,U.[Col2] = SourceData.Col2
   ,U.[Col3] = SourceData.Col3
FROM dbo.TargetTable U
     INNER JOIN dbo.OtherTable T ON T.PrimaryKey=U.FKRecId AND T.Type=KnownType
     INNER JOIN dbo.TargetTable SourceData ON SourceData.FKRecId=@SourceRecordId
WHERE U.FKRecId!=@SourceRecordId AND 
      (CAST(U.Col1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) != CAST(SourceData.Col1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) OR 
       CAST(U.Col2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) != CAST(SourceData.Col2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) OR 
       CAST(U.Col3 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) != CAST(SourceData.Col3 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) )
```

Basically, the FROM and WHERE clause would be identical as for a SELECT statement. In the first line of the UPDATE statement you need to mention the alias of the table you want to update and in the SET part you specify the columns of that alias on the left side of the equals sign.

If the Col1, Col2 and Col3 columns are nullable, then you have to take care that the compare's will work correctly in case of NULL's.

Comment: Hi - this worked for me perfectly, thanks for quick reponse

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning `FKRecId` column from `SourceData` subquery and attempting to access it with `TargetTable` whilst you already assigned a `SourceData` alias to that subquery and must use it:

```
 FROM ( SELECT FKRecId, Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM TargetTable WHERE FKRecId = @SourceRecordId ) SourceData
 JOIN dbo.OtherTable t On t.PrimaryKey = SourceData.FKRecId
 WHERE ((FKRecId != @SourceRecordId) AND (t.Type = KnownType) AND
```

or without subquery

```
 SELECT
      tt.FKRecId, 
      tt.Col1, 
      tt.Col2, 
      tt.Col3 
 FROM TargetTable as tt
 JOIN dbo.OtherTable t On t.PrimaryKey = tt.FKRecId
 WHERE t.FKRecId != @SourceRecordId AND t.Type = KnownType
    AND tt.FKRecId = @SourceRecordId
```

not sure if combination of filters with `@SourceRecordId` is logically okay.